# Is the male satin bowerbird's bower-building behavior innate?

Tags: ornithology, ethology

The male [satin bowerbird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satin_bowerbird) builds a stick structure, known as a *bower* (distinct from a nest), where courtship and mating take place.  They curiously decorate their bowers using blue or shiny objects.

[image: Male satin bowerbird bower]

(Image source: [Wikimedia commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Satin_Bowerbird_nest.jpg).)

> When courting, the male satin bowerbird prances and struts around his bower. He offers the female items from his collection of blue objects, while making a series of hissing, chattering and scolding noises. Mating takes place in the avenue of the bower, and the male may mate with several females in a single season.  -- [NSW Government Office Of Environment and Heritage](http://www.environment.nsw.gov.au/animals/Bowerbirds.htm)

*Question*: Is the male satin bowerbird's bower-building behavior innate?

This is essentially a "nature vs. nurture" question.  E.g. If there were no other males around for him to learn it from, would he still build a bower?  If so, where did he get the idea from?  If there were no females around, would he still bother to build it?

Comment: Does your question allow for both possibilities simultaneously (nature and nurture)?

Comment: I guess it has to allow for both, as it could be the case.  (Mentioning nature vs. nurture was just to convey the spirit of the question; I'm not seriously suggesting these are the only two possibilities.)